# Magento 2 success page error

Tags: magento2

I'm using magento 2, upgraded to the last version 2.4.6-p2, and I'm having an issue with the success page, but not with all payment methods...

What I get in the success page is:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Unknown Config Class

Exception #0 (Exception): Unknown Config Class
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php:44]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:272]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:252]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:229]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:134]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:93]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:365]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:32]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:65]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:271]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:896]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/Observer/SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver.php:61]
#20 Magento\GoogleAnalytics\Observer\SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:88]
#21 Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:74]
#22 Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:65]
#23 Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php:95]
#24 Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php:33]
#25 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#26 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#27 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#28 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success/Interceptor.php:23]
#29 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage.php:161]
#31 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#32 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#33 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [app/code/Webkul/RewardSystem/Plugin/App/Action/Context.php:55]
#34 Webkul\RewardSystem\Plugin\App\Action\Context->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#35 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#36 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success/Interceptor.php:32]
#37 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:245]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:212]
#39 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:147]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#41 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#42 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#43 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#44 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:75]
#45 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#46 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#47 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#48 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#49 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#50 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]
</pre>
```

I get this error with default cash on delivery payment, bank transfer and also paypall.
Using php 8.1, no errors in magento and apache logs.

Can anyone help me?

Best regards,
Leonel Nunes

Answer (score 1):

The error message mentions a class called `"Webkul\RewardSystem\Plugin\App\Action\Context"` which may be related to a custom plugin. Ensure that the class exists and is properly configured or disabled temporarily.

If still getting errors then you should disable all third-party extensions one by one and check with Recompile and Flush Cache.

Check the Magento log files ('`var/log/system.log`' and '`var/log/exception.log`') for any additional error messages or stack traces that might provide more information about the issue.

Remember to back up your code and database before making significant changes, and proceed with caution when modifying configuration files or uninstalling modules

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I will try disabling webkul module and check if the problem persists. There are no eror in the logs.

Comment: Did you run CLI commands after disabling third-party extension?

Comment: Hello, and thanks again for the reply. No, I will try again with the CLI commands

Comment: Hello again, disabled the extension and the problem persists.

Comment: run this commands `rm -rf generated/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/*`

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
`php bin/magento cache:clean`
`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Hello again and thanks, already did that, but didn't removed de folders before the commands. I can try that and let you know if it solved the problem.

Comment: Hello, I found the guilty extension, it was the one of other payments. Already contacted the support for them to provide an update. Thanks for the helps :). Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should run composer upgrade first and if there is any error is occurred then you should resolve first.
And also you should check all required php extension are installed.

Even, this process not solve your issue then you should disable all third party extension then try and after the run successfully you should one by one enabled extension and check which extension raising issue.

In your shared error log nothing showing any issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to run composer upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The module `Webkul_RewardSystem` causing the issue.

Check after disabling it, It's a third party module.

If success page working after disable the module `Webkul_RewardSystem`,Then check the `Webkul\RewardSystem\Plugin\App\Action\Context->aroundDispatch()` class

Comment: Tabk you for your answer, I will try to disable it and find if it's working

Comment: Hello, not working after disabling the module :(

Comment: check with luma theme once

Comment: Well, I've disabled the webkul extension (in the extention page not in magento) but still get the line "#33 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [app/code/Webkul/RewardSystem/Plugin/App/Action/Context.php:55]". I've checked in the webkull page and there is and update so I'll see if the problem is solved and if the problem is from there...